# Difference between drawing directly to canvas and drawing on bitmap and then canvas in Android onDraw()

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm writing a custom view that displays signals. In order to shorten my onDraw() time I cache everything I've drawn so far in a Bitmap and just append to that in every onDraw() call. By doing this I can save huge amounts of time since I only need to draw a few fixels at a time instead of redoing the whole thing.

There is on thing bothering me though - it appears as drawing directly to the provided canvas provides a more "accurate" drawing than drawing on the bitmap first and then drawing the bitmap on the canvas. By looking at the lower part of the following picture you can see the difference:

[image: Look at the lower part of the signal to see difference - there are the same drawLine calls]

I uploaded a demo project displaying the discrepancy at [https://github.com/gardarh/android-uglybitmapdrawing/](https://github.com/gardarh/android-uglybitmapdrawing) but the relevant code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(cachedBitmap == null) {
        cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
        cachedCanvas = new Canvas(cachedBitmap);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < COORDS.length; i++) {
        float[] curCoords = COORDS[i];
        canvas.drawLine(curCoords[0], curCoords[1], curCoords[2], curCoords[3], linePaint);
        cachedCanvas.drawLine(curCoords[0], curCoords[1], curCoords[2], curCoords[3], linePaint);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap, 0, 120, null);
}
```

Why are the two traces not the same and more importantly, how can I make the lower trace look like the upper one?

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for sharing your code. I am also trying to make an app that displays signals as graphs on the Android screen and your code is helping me get some ideas. However I am also a beginner in Android and so have a  few basic questions regarding your code, so please bear with me if these questions are too trivial. First question is, there is no code in the MainActivity class that calls any functions from the CachedDrawingJava class, but I was able to find out that the onDraw() function in that other class gets called at least once. When and how does this call happen?

Comment: My graph needs to be draw within a rectangular area specified within my apps screen, but the sample graphing codes I have been able to find till now do so over the full screen. In your code, are the black squiggly lines being drawn on a graph that occupies a full screen, or just a part of the screen? Which part of your code deals with this?

Comment: This is the only line in the activity that matters: 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Now let's look at https://github.com/gardarh/android-uglybitmapdrawing/blob/master/res/layout/activity_main.xml:

You'll see this:  <com.noxmedical.cachedviewtest.CachedDrawingView ... />

Which in turn takes us to https://github.com/gardarh/android-uglybitmapdrawing/blob/master/src/com/noxmedical/cachedviewtest/CachedDrawingView.java - where all the work is done in onDraw(). The system calls onDraw() for me every time it feels like it needs to redraw the screen, so it's automatic.

Comment: The size of the view is controlled by the layout xml file (in my case layout_height and layout_width is set to match_parent which fills the screen) but you can set it to a fixed width, e.g. layout_width="100dp" layout_height="100dp". Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the differences is that the canvas drawing is done by hardware acceleration (GPU), and the bitmap drawing is done by software (CPU). If you disable hardware acceleration, they become the exact same.
If you multiply the X coordinates by 10, you will see that the difference is in the way lines are joined. These are minor one pixel difference and I wouldn't bother with them. I am not sure which one is the more accurate, they seem like just slightly different implementations.

Comment: That's true, verified by disabling HW acceleration. How odd, though.

Answer (score 4):

Android framework API provides 2D drawing APIs for simple animation that does not require major dynamic changes.
 There are two ways of implementation using these API.

**1. Drawing to a View 

    2. Drawing on a Canvas**

**1.Drawing a circle to  View** 
                Drawing to view is a better option when your UI does not require dynamic changes in the application. 
This can be achieved simply by extending the View class and define an **onDraw()** callback method. 
 Use the Canvas given to you for all your drawing,
using various Canvas.draw...() methods (Ex: canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);). onDraw() is a callback method invoked when the view is initially drawn.

Below is a simple example code to draw a circle:- 
**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(new MyView(this));
     }

     public class MyView extends View {
         public MyView(Context context) {
              super(context);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FB9J2F"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
     } }
```

**2. Drawing rectangle on a canvas**

To draw dynamic 2D graphics where in your application needs to regularly re draw itself, drawing on a canvas is a better option. A Canvas works for you as an interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn.

If you need to create a new Canvas, then you must define the bitmap upon which drawing will actually be performed. The Bitmap is always required for a Canvas.
The below example explains to draw a rectangle:- 
 **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout">     </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#DD4N5C"));
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
        canvas.drawRect(150, 150, 250, 250, paint); 
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));   
     }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that you are saving much by going the bitmap route. You might consider a data structure that stores the drawn signal and converting this to a JSON object that can be serialized/deserialized.
As for your question, this is an educated guess but it has more to do with rescaling of the drawn signal, since you are not using getHeight() when you create the bitmap.

Comment: Using a bitmap saves a lot of time, I measured it. Note that this a only a fraction of a larger drawing. The bitmap should not be scaled at all, the canvas.drawBitmap() signature I use should not scale the bitmap - I use the constant 200 instead of the getHeight() method for simplification, it should not matter. There are other potential ways to to do this, e.g. use SurfaceView. However, right now I'm only interested in knowing why there is a different in the resulting images.